Installing Ubuntu 24.04 on X64
I have a Microsoft Surface Studio 1, which has an Intel 64 bit. I'm only seeing installation media for AMD-64. I did download the AMD-64, but it will not boot from USB. Is there a different installer for an Intel 64 bit processor?

Nope, AMD-64 is for both AMD and Intel. Try to verify the ISO file before it is written to USB.

Thanks - I have verified the download. I may have to disable Secure Boot.

See Is the 64-Bit version of Ubuntu only compatible with AMD CPUs?

Intel's IA64 processor was abandoned long ago... Intel now only sell amd64 compatible processors  (don't forget the market place chose amd64 long ago with only a few machines being sold in Intel's 64bit replacement for the prior x86; the lack of backwards compatibility just caused the amd64 to be preferred by consumers leading to Intel only selling AMD64 for years now; they just pay to do it & don't mention the AMD64 official name).

FYI:  You mention only release (24.04), where ISOs are available for different products (Server; using subiquity installer, Deskop using ubuntu-desktop-installer, and some flavors that even use calamares), but you didn't mention which 24.04 you downloaded & thus what installer you attempted.. but I suspect your issue is not installer related.  Its helpful if your specific with details; ie. you didn't specify which 24.04 ISO you downloaded

I didn't realize that the iA64 processor was dead. I got my computer in 2018. I downloaded the Desktop installer.

You're unlikely to have an IA64 processor; windows server was the only OS created by Microsoft for that CPU; so I'm betting you're after an amd64 system (ie. intel CPU like I have on this box; made by Intel under license as are all their pentium/i-series range). If not amd64 it'll be ARM

This is my processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6820HQ CPU @ 2.70GHz   2.71 GHz

The pentium/core2 & i-series processors by intel are all amd64 (with fees paid to AMD to use the technology, though as AMD pay for pre-64bit use of x86 the fee deals aren't one way).  Your CPU/processor is amd64.  Intel's 64-bit was IA-64 discontinued by intel in 2019 (the marketplace wanted backward compatibility which amd64 provided)

Given that my computer was purchased in 2018, if the IA-64 was not discontinued until 2019, then it is quite possible that my processor is an actual IA-64. What I do know is that when I boot the Ubuntu USB, the Grub menu does come up. I can select the option to Try or Install Ubuntu, the screen goes dark and nothing further happens. Interesting is that when I return to Windows, my date/time has been reset to UTC instead of Eastern Daylight. It is not dependent on time, since I have left the Ubuntu USB trying to boot for more than an hour.

Microsoft announced they were abandoning support for IA64 in 2010; though Linux supported IA64 for longer (in Servers). You said your processor is an Intel Core i7 which is an AMD64 processor and not IA64 (all Intel Core processors are amd64, as well as all Intel i-series processor). It is backwards compatible with x86 (IA64 is not!).  Your issue is likely related specific to your hardware (which maybe rather unique rather than standard) but I don't see what you actually tried to install (ie. I see only release details 24.04 of which there are a number of choices just in amd64)

I don't get the option to install. The menu item allows for try or install. If I select that option, nothing further is displayed, although I have observed that my time is set to UTC when I reboot back to Windows.
